# Why is z-index ignored with position:static?

Tags: jquery, html, css, z-index

See this comment [from jquery-ui](http://www.google.com/codesearch#NjeLL32WYDs/trunk/ui/jquery.ui.core.js&q=zindex%20package%3ahttp://jquery-ui%5C.googlecode%5C.com&l=154)

```
// Ignore z-index if position is set to a value where z-index is ignored by the browser
// This makes behavior of this function consistent across browsers
// WebKit always returns auto if the element is positioned
```

I see that jquery's `zIndex()` returns 0 if the element is `position: static`.

Isn't z-index supported on position:static? (It works for me in Chrome, haven't tested cross-browser)

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814282/why-is-my-z-index-being-ignored

Comment: @Dve - not really. The answer to that qusetion is `It does not apply to elements with static position.` I'm asking **why** that is.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Because `position: static` means "Ignore all the positioning instructions from `left`, `top`, `z-index`, etc.".

```
'z-index'
Value:      auto | <integer> | inherit
Initial:    auto
Applies to:     positioned elements
```

— http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#z-index

> An element is said to be positioned if its 'position' property has a value other than 'static'.

— http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#positioned-element

Answer (score 14):

`z-index` is not ignored for flex-items (immediate children of flex-container, element with `display: flex` or `display: inline-flex`) or grid-items (immediate children of grid-container, element with `display: grid` or `display: inline-grid`).

#### Specs quotation

From [W3C Flexbox specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#painting):

> [Flex items](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-item) paint exactly the same as inline blocks [CSS21](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#biblio-css21), except that [`order`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#propdef-order)-modified document order is used in place of raw document order, and [`z-index`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-positioning/#propdef-z-index) values other than [`auto`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-positioning/#valdef-z-index-auto) create a stacking context even if [`position`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-positioning/#propdef-position) is [`static`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-positioning/#valdef-position-static).

From [W3C CSS Grid Layout specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#z-order):

> [Grid items](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#grid-item) can overlap when they are positioned into intersecting [grid areas](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#grid-area), or even when positioned in non-intersecting areas because of negative margins or positioning. The painting order of [grid items](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#grid-item) is exactly the same as inline blocks [CSS21](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#biblio-css21), except that [order-modified document order](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#order-modified-document-order) is used in place of raw document order, and [`z-index`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-positioning/#propdef-z-index) values other than [`auto`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-positioning/#valdef-z-index-auto) create a stacking context even if [`position`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-positioning/#propdef-position) is [`static`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-positioning/#valdef-position-static) (behaving exactly as if [`position`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-positioning/#propdef-position) were [`relative`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-positioning/#valdef-position-relative)). Thus the [`z-index`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-positioning/#propdef-z-index) property can easily be used to control the z-axis order of grid items.

#### Flexbox example

So assume we have this layout with overlapping (`.flex-item-two` overlaps `.flex-item-one` using e.g. negative margins):

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.flex-item-one {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-right: -50px;
}

.flex-item-two {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="flex-item flex-item-one">One</div>
  <div class="flex-item flex-item-two">Two</div>
</div>
```

If `flex-item-one` index is bigger than `.flex-item-two`'s, `.flex-item-one` then overlaps `.flex-item-two`.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.flex-item-one {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-right: -50px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.flex-item-two {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="flex-item flex-item-one">One</div>
  <div class="flex-item flex-item-two">Two</div>
</div>
```

#### CSS Grid example

```css
#grid {
  display: inline-grid;
  width: 250px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr
}

#A {
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  grid-row: 2;
  align-self: end;
  background-color: #4f81bd;
}

#B {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #8064a2;
}

#C {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1;
  align-self: start;
  margin-left: -20px;
  background-color: #f79646;
}

#D {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 2;
  justify-self: end;
  align-self: start;
  background-color: #9bbb59;
}

#E {
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
  z-index: 5;
  justify-self: center;
  align-self: center;
  background-color: #c0504d;
}

#grid > * {
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 20px 40px;
  font-size: 32px;
}

#C, #D {
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
  <div id="A">A</div>
  <div id="B">B</div>
  <div id="C">C</div>
  <div id="D">D</div>
  <div id="E">E</div>
</div>
```

Comment: How did you come across this? Can u recommend some book or resource where i can find these kind of tricky cases. Thanks.

Comment: @RezvanChagaev I was studying CSS Flexbox and CSS Grid by different sources, so I can't recommend anything.