# Jquery & CSS - Overlapping divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to create a expnd divs when user mouse over with Jquery and CSS.
My **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ua444/)** works great into Opera Browser but into Chrome when i hover the box "B" and return to box "A" this is overlaped by the box "B". How to solve it?. Here's my code block:

HTML:

```
<div id="box">
    <div class="inner" id="01">
        <a href="#" class="block">
            <span id="s01" class="s01">A</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="inner" id="02">
        <a href="#" class="block">
            <span id="s02" class="s01">B</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {

    background-color:navy;
}
#box {
    height: 92px;
    _height: 92px; 
    width: 290px;
    _width: 270px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 9px;
    margin-top: 48px;
    margin-bottom: 31px;
    margin-right: 26px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    _overflow:hidden;
}
.inner {
    height: 90px;
    width: 141.6px;
    _width: 121.6px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 0px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #2DA2A8;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index:0;
}
.s01 {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    height:100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding-top: 36px;
}
.block {
    color:#399;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    $("#01").mouseover(function(){$(this).css({
      transition:"all 1s",transform:"scale(1.2)","z-index":"2",
      "background-color":"#24C9C4","border-top":"solid 1px white",
       "border-bottom":"solid 1px white"})})

     $("#01").mouseout(function(){$(this).css({
       transition:"all 1s",transform:"scale(1.0)","z-index":"0",
        "background-color":"#FFF","border-top":"none",
         "border-bottom":"none"})})


     $("#02").mouseover(function(){$(this).css({
      transition:"all 1s",transform:"scale(1.2)","z-index":"2",
      "background-color":"#24C9C4","border-top":"solid 1px white",
       "border-bottom":"solid 1px white"})})

     $("#02").mouseout(function(){$(this).css({
       transition:"all 1s",transform:"scale(1.0)","z-index":"0",
        "background-color":"#FFF","border-top":"none",
         "border-bottom":"none"})})

});
```

Comment: Not sure what version of Opera it works for you, but both in Chrome (31.0.1650.63) and Opera (18.0.1284.68) B overlaps A for me. The overlapping is the expected behaviour though

Comment: @heartcode My Opera version is 12.15 Build 1748.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the neatest way to solve this is to add `position:relative` to the divs, this will enable `z-index` to work.

If you don't do this, the divs are defaulted to `position:static` which ignores `z-index`, see: [Why is z-index ignored with position:static?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8486475/why-is-z-index-ignored-with-positionstatic)

There is more information here, which explains why it works in Opera but not Chrome: http://yagudaev.com/posts/getting-reliable-z-index-cross-browser/

`position:absolute` would work as well if you wanted to use that instead, but you would need to specify exactly where you want the divs to be placed.

Updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ua444/1/

You already had a class on those divs so the only change is:

```
.inner {    
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've forked and updated your fiddle.

The z-index and relative positioning should work:
http://jsfiddle.net/robertp/y48BD/

I removed the z-index manipulation from the JavaScript and used :hover state to change the z-index instead:

```
  .inner {
    ...
    position: relative;
  } 

  .inner:hover {
    z-index: 1;
  }
```

I hope this is something you've been after.

Comment: Not sure why, but in his response to div "A" is taking a little longer to override the div "B", I think I should keep the z-index in javascript. Anyway thanks.