# Why doesn't the z-index style apply to the <body> element?

Tags: html, css, z-index, document-body

The `z-index` style allows you to control what order boxes are painted in. For example, you can make a child element be painted below its parent element:

```css
#parent {
  background: rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.7);
}
#child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent"><div id="child"></div></div>
```

However, when the parent element is the `<body>` tag, this no longer behaves as expected:

```css
body {
  background: rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.7);
}
#child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="child"></div>
</body>
```

[The CSS specification §9.9.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#z-index) states (emphasis mine):

> **The root element forms the root stacking context.** Other stacking contexts are generated by any positioned element (including relatively positioned elements) having a computed value of 'z-index' other than 'auto'. Stacking contexts are not necessarily related to containing blocks. In future levels of CSS, other properties may introduce stacking contexts, for example '[opacity](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#transparency)' [[CSS3COLOR]](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/refs.html#ref-CSS3COLOR).
>
> Within each stacking context, the following layers are painted in back-to-front order:
>
> 1. **the background and borders of the element forming the stacking context**.
> 2. **the child stacking contexts with negative stack levels (most negative first).**
> 3. the in-flow, non-inline-level, non-positioned descendants.
> 4. the non-positioned floats.
> 5. the in-flow, inline-level, non-positioned descendants, including inline tables and inline blocks.
> 6. the child stacking contexts with stack level 0 and the positioned descendants with stack level 0.
> 7. the child stacking contexts with positive stack levels (least positive first).

If `<body>` were the root element, then this behavior would make sense, since that would mean that the `<body>` element is always painted first no matter what.

However, in an HTML document, `<html>` is the root element. Given that, why can't we place an element under `<body>` with the `z-index` style?

---

(This question was motivated by a [similar question on the Russian Stack Overflow site](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/444089/176684).)

Comment: just like how overflow hidden doesnt work on body

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue here is that if the html element doesn't have a background specified, the canvas adopts the background of the body element, and that gets painted first. [CSS 2.1 says](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/colors.html#background):

> For documents whose root element is an HTML "HTML" element or an XHTML
>   "html" element that has computed values of 'transparent' for
>   'background-color' and 'none' for 'background-image', user agents must
>   instead use the computed value of the background properties from that
>   element's first HTML "BODY" element or XHTML "body" element child when
>   painting backgrounds for the canvas, and must not paint a background
>   for that child element.

See what happens when the html element is given a background:

```css
html { 
  background-color: white;
}

body {
  background: rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.7);
}
#child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="child"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: This makes the most sense to me of anything so far, is there a reason why it was deleted earlier?

Comment: I deleted it while I double-checked my facts.

Comment: Thanks for this, I hope you don't mind if I [borrow the gist of this answer to answer the related question on the Russian site](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/444095/176684).

Answer (score 9):

`<body>` tag's [default positioning](http://phrogz.net/css/htmlvsbody.html) is `static`. And by definition static positioning means *ignore all positioning instructions*.

In other words because z-index property does not apply to elements that have `position:static`, it does not apply to `body` as it's position defaults to `static`

Here's a good [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8486475/why-is-z-index-ignored-with-positionstatic) on why z-index does not work on `position:static`

> Update: So why doesn't it work with body { position:relative } ?

Because `body` get's a [stacking context](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/what-you-may-not-know-about-the-z-index-property--webdesign-16892). Now with z-index, a element can only go behind or forward relative to its `siblings` but never behind its parent.  Because `body` is a `parent` element, setting negative z-index on it's child does not take it behind body.

Comment: If you change Body position to relative its still the same

Comment: In that case, why doesn't it work when you add `body {position: relative;}`?

Comment: @PeterOlson great question. Please check my update on the answer that tries to answer this.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to find official, or even authoritative, documentation on this issue, probably because it's not a common real-life scenario, but the issue has been discussed before by **Ian Hickson** and **Tantek Celik**, the editors of the [CSS Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/).

Below are some parts of a [thread from a W3C mailing list](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/1999Aug/0131.html) in which spec writers discuss the behavior of `z-index` in relation to the `body` element.

The essence of the discussion is this:

- The browser is right to ignore `z-index` on non-positioned elements (like `body`), because `z-index` applies only to positioned elements
- z-indexing of an element is relative only to sibling elements, and not to parent elements, due to the creation of [stacking contexts](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/zindex.html)

  > ... a child box cannot circumvent the z-order of its parent.  it can
  >   place itself behind or in front of any of its siblings, but it cannot
  >   place itself behind it's parent box.  it can place itself in such a
  >   way that it is first child rendered before any other child ....
- There's also an interesting note about the behavior of `z-index` with `position: fixed` on the `body` element, but it [doesn't look like it was  implemented](http://jsfiddle.net/c003arws/).

---

*Tantek Celik:*

> I've got a question regarding the `z-index` property: Why can I still
>   see elements which I've put *behind* the BODY element (see example
>   below)?
>
> Because your browser has a bug or doesn't support `z-index`.
>
> Or the browser *doesn't* have a bug and is properly ignoring `z-index`
>   on non-positioned elements.
>
> <BODY STYLE="z-index: 0; background-color: #456789;">
>  
>   <P STYLE="z-index: -1; color: #fedcba;">This is a test showing a text
>   that shouldn't be visible as it lies behind the body element
>   <EM>("z-index" property equals "-1").</EM>
>   </BODY>
>
> In the example given, both elements which have a `z-index` *do not* have
>   their position property set, and since according to:
>
> http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS2/visuren.html#z-index
>
> the z-index property "Applies to: positioned elements", the settings
>   on the `z-index` property are ignored.
>
> Tantek

*response from spec writer*:

> hi,
>
> (Tantek: i do agree with you that the spec says `z-index` is only for
>   *positioned* elements, but as Ian says, i don't see why it cannot be applied for static boxes which overlap due to negative margins.)
>
> look at the following markup:
>
> <body style="z-index=0; background-color=green;">
>   <p style="z-index=-1; position: relative; top: 50; left: 20"> hello!!
>   </p>
>   <p> world!! </p>
>   </body>
>
> P is a child of BODY, and according the CSS2 spec (my reading, anyway
>   :) z-indexing of an element is relative only to sibling elements, and
>   not to parent elements.  this has to do with the creation of a z-index
>   contexts.
>
> so the box for 'hello!!' would show up behind the box for 'world!!'
>   but NOT behind the box for BODY because BODY contains both P element
>   boxes.
>
> !!! please correct if i'm wrong on this, because if i am, i have to
>   redo my renderer so that it does not respect hierarchical boundaries,
>   which is NOT a happy situation.  !!!
>
> the original intent of this thread (the question) can be attained by
>   making the `z-index=-1` box a `position: fixed` box (though the
>   positioning properties would be complex.)  this would work because
>   fixed boxes break out of the hierarchy where they are found and
>   levitate to the viewport box, essentially becoming a sibling to the
>   BODY box.
>
> -- ranjit

*spec writer:*

> please,
>
> pardon my use of implementation specific terms.
>
> you are correct about the HTML assumption.  but my point remains
>   valid, even if we look at the hierarchy of the document/box structure
>   regardless of markup.
>
> currently, in my implementation, the following implicit rule is
>   dictated by the hierarchical structure of the boxes generated by
>   parsing a hierarchical document structure (XML, HTML, ...)
>
> RULE: a child box cannot circumvent the z-order of its parent.  it can
>   place itself behind or in front of any of its siblings, but it cannot
>   place itself behind it's parent box.  it can place itself in such a
>   way that it is first child rendered before any other child, ....
>
> i see this rule implied by the CSS2 spec as well, in the section where
>   there is talk of z-order contexts and so on.
>
> as i see it, z-order values for a CHILD boxes are valid within the
>   parent z-order context.  this can be illustrated with absolute
>   positioned boxes containing absolute positioned boxes where a child
>   absolute boxes have a z-ordering that cannot violate the z-ordering of
>   the parent absolute boxes.
>
> again, let me say: if i have misunderstood something in the spec, let
>   me know, for if the above rule is invalid, then it seems to me the
>   notion of hierarchy is not preserved for non-fixed boxes.
>
> regards,
>
> -- ranjit

http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/1999Aug/0131.html

Comment: wow, you're a legend! how did you find this!

Answer (score 0):

The `<body>` tag is defaulted to stay on the bottom of the stack. It simply cannot be set as it will always be the lowest possible value.

Source: [Adobe Forums](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/990152)

Answer (score 0):

Well, there isn't much documentation about this.

But the `<body>` tag can't have any siblings, so why would ever be a need to change its z-index?

Is it even considered a 'positioned' element?

You may play with its child elements z-index as you wish and get desired results in any situation, there is no need to over-complicate html with css styles with no reason at all