# Onclick function error, function isn't defined

Tags: javascript, queryselector

Over the recent days I've been trying to make buttons that changes a text's color by using

> document.querySelector.('class name').style.color

in a function while using `onclick` to put that function in the button, but it always says my function *changeColor isn't defined.* Could some of you help me please? It also says there's an unexpected token, please help me with that as well!

```html
<body>
    <div class="box">
      <h1> Hello</h1>
    </div>
       <script>
function changeColor(){
  document.querySelector.('.box').style.color = 'pink';
}
    </script>
    <button class="pink">Pink</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have an extra dot in `querySelector.('.box')`, should be `document.querySelector('.box').style.color = 'pink';` and you never attacth a listener so your function is never triggered.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add javascript onclick event listener to container div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69859249/how-to-add-javascript-onclick-event-listener-to-container-div)

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's nothing in your code here that would even try to call your function so  I can't say for sure what your issue is, but to hook up the `click` event of the button to your function, you use: [`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Now, you do have a typo:

```
document.querySelector.('.box') // <-- The dot before ( is wrong
```

And your `script` element should be the last thing before you close the `body` tag so that by the time the script runs, all the HTML will have been parsed into memory.

```html
<div class="box">
  <h1> Hello</h1>
</div>
<button class="pink">Pink</button>
 
<script>
  document.querySelector("button.pink").addEventListener("click", changeColor);
  function changeColor(){
    document.querySelector('.box').style.color = 'pink';
  }
</script>
```

And while this works, inline styles should be avoided whenever possible because they are the hardest type of CSS styling to override and lead to duplication of code. Instead, use CSS classes whenever you can (almost always) as shown here:

```css
.pinkText { color:pink; }
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <h1> Hello</h1>
</div>
<button class="pink">Pink</button>
 
<script>
  // Get your DOM element references just once, not every time the function runs:
  const box = document.querySelector('.box');
  document.querySelector("button.pink").addEventListener("click", changeColor);
  function changeColor(){
    box.classList.add('pinkText');
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <div class="box">
      <h1> Hello</h1>
    </div>
    <button class="pink" onclick="changeColor()">Pink</button>
  </body>
       <script>
function changeColor(){
  document.querySelector('.box h1').style.color = 'pink';
}
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Please don't just provide code for your answer. What about your post answers the question, and why?

Answer (score 0):

There are two simple mistakes in your code that can be easily fixed.

1. There is an extra dot before the parenthesis in your function.  Since `querySelector` is a function, the parenthesis with the attributes come directly after it, as shown below.

```
document.querySelector('.box').style.color = 'pink';
```

2. There isn't anything to trigger the onclick event.  The simplest way to fix this is to add an `onclick` attribute to your button, as shown below:

```
<button class="pink" onclick="changeColor()">Pink</button>
```

I hope that this can help.