# Navbar works on one page but not on another

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navigationbar

I'm trying to complete my portfolio, and the last thing I did was to polish the navbar a bit. I changed the position from `fixed` to `static` since it was blocking some text etc. However, in the index page it goes under the header img/text, when on the other pages it works perfectly.

Index: http://prntscr.com/az3epm

Other page: http://prntscr.com/az3es4

How can I fix that problem ?

The code: http://pastebin.com/raw/fsANa932

Answer (score 1):

Use `relative` position instead of the default `static` and make sure your slider in your index page has a lower `z-index` number and it should be good.

Also, you could check out this very good explanation of how `z-index` works here : 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7490187/6028607

And you can check this answer to understand why `static` position is ignored with `z-index` property : 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8486532/6028607

Comment: Do you have a slideshow on the index page ? If so, you have to change the z-index of the slideshow to make it appear behind the nav

Comment: Can you post the index code on a jsFiddle please ? https://jsfiddle.net/ 
Otherwise, it's not easy to debug

Comment: Lowered width from 33.33% to 31% so it can be inline style . https://jsfiddle.net/eL7fbn04/

Comment: Yes but I was thinking, can you post **all** the index code ? Because your navbar is working good but is hide because of the next content

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/u33gi6ruz7azxyh/AACBdjyiFDApTuO0_WL5xrr_a?dl=0 , the whole project :D , It has some libraries etc so its hard to copy the index

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110774/discussion-between-vincent-g-and-vaggelisd).