# Position relative div1 above position absolute div2 relative to div3

Tags: html, css

The page content is showing above the absolute dropdown with more options relative to the sticky breadcrumb.

I've tried playing with z-index and positions but the only solution I found was to remove the position relative on the content which isn't an option.

How do I get 'div2' above 'div1'?

**EDIT:** https://jsfiddle.net/6ncp7f1q/1/

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="breadcrumb">
    Home
    <div class="extra">
      <a href="#">TextText</a>
      <a href="#">TextText</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.breadcrumb{
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: pink;
}

.extra{
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  right: 0;
  top: 40px;
}

.extra a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.content{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  color: green;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Some code or a fiddle would be helpful here.

Comment: A jfiddle was provided @rmn

Comment: didn't you try with this .extra{  z-index:1;}

Comment: If you were to have read the second paragraph I mentioned I did and it didn't work

Comment: @Wanjia you want the red links to appear above the content ?

Comment: Yes I do, was my question unclear?

Comment: @UdaraKasun is right, adding `z-index: 1` to `.extra` works, at least editing it in your fiddle it does. Did we get it right, or you're looking for a different result.

Comment: i think it's the solution as you want

Comment: It seems to work here, let me try and recreate my issue where it doesn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my z-index being ignored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814282/why-is-my-z-index-being-ignored)

Comment: I found out that position sticky was causing this problem and accidentally typed "relative" instead of sticky while I did not know this was the cause of the problem. I didn't wanted to delete the question as to people might helped by the reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
.extra{
  z-index:1;
}
```

Example here: https://jsfiddle.net/4er5vcop/2/

Answer (score 0):

I hope to helpful this

```
   .extra{
      z-index:1;
    }
```

here is the result

https://jsfiddle.net/L8mpv79a/

Answer (score 0):

just set z-index to breadcrumb

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.breadcrumb{
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: pink;
  z-index:99;
}

.extra{
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  right: 0;
  top: 20px;
}

.extra a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.content{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="breadcrumb">
    Home
    <div class="extra">
      <a href="#">TextText</a>
      <a href="#">TextText</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <p>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text </p>
  </div>
</div>
```