# how to use z-index in overlay and text

Tags: css

i want to use z-index for text and overlay.

https://jsfiddle.net/osm2rkbx/1/

it is my code.

```css
.mainArea {
    background: url('https://c.wallhere.com/photos/94/68/1920x1000_px_landscape_photography_reflections_river-1002111.jpg!d');
    height: 50vh;
    width: 100vw;
    position: relative;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.mainArea p {
    display: flex;
    height: 50vh;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: 800;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #000000;
    z-index: 999999 !important;
}

.mainAreaOverlay {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainArea">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center ">
                <p>its the text..</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mainAreaOverlay"></div>
</div>
```

when i use z-index for text, its not working. It seems pale. How can i see text with white. İf you help me i will be glad, thanks.

Comment: Read about stacking context https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context

Comment: Does this answer your question? [z-index isn't applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814282/z-index-isnt-applied)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put *z-index:-1* in **mainArea** class and update *z-index:-1* to **mainAreaOverlay** class.

Old mainArea class:

```
.mainArea {
    background: url('https://c.wallhere.com/photos/94/68/1920x1000_px_landscape_photography_reflections_river-1002111.jpg!d');
    height: 50vh;
    width: 100vw;
    position: relative;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Updated:

```
.mainArea {
    background: url('https://c.wallhere.com/photos/94/68/1920x1000_px_landscape_photography_reflections_river-1002111.jpg!d');
    height: 50vh;
    width: 100vw;
    position: relative;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

Old mainAreaOverlay class:

```
.mainAreaOverlay {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Updated:

```
.mainAreaOverlay {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```